# Flask - how to keep list index after form submit?

Tags: python, flask

I have a list of images that I want to display on a page. These image names are formatted basically `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg`.  I want this single page to either list all images, or only list and show those taken on a certain date (meaning a main page, not like `/index` to show all images, `/date-specific` to show some images).

So far, I have been able to show *all* images, and click "next"/"previous" buttons to loop through all images.  I also have a table below the image, showing all the images that are in the index.

Works great - no issues.

However, I am also trying to implement a date filter, where the user can select a date from the Calendar Picker, and have the site filter out and only show photos on that day.  So far, I can successfully filter *one* time.  However, when I click "next"/"previous" buttons, or choose an image from the table, it resets back to the full list of images.

How do I keep the filtered list?  I thought I could do it by keeping the date chosen in the Input field, but after using the "next"/"previous" buttons, the whole page resets and it clears that field.

I also tried including the list in the HTML portion, but it still returns *all* the photos. (Also makes the URL ugly, since it includes the image list for *each* photo listed in the table):

```
<td><a href="{{ url_for('default_template', chosen_image=image, image_list=image_list) }}"> {{ image }} </a></td>
```

[Here's a .gif of the page I'm working on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kbzR.gif). First, you'll see I can successfully click around, navigate between *all* photos.  Then, I can successfully filter to show photos on a specific date.  However, anything past that keeps sending me back to the *full* image list.

Anyways, without further ado, here's the codes. (Note I try to keep it minimal, so might have omitted an important piece, so please let me know if I need to post something else here):

routes.py

```
import os
import random
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, Blueprint, redirect  # noqa
from app import app

IMAGE_FOLDER = r"C:/MyPath/Test"
FAVORITE_LIST = os.path.join(IMAGE_FOLDER, "favorites.txt")

blueprint = Blueprint('images', __name__,
                      static_url_path='/static/images',
                      static_folder=IMAGE_FOLDER)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

images = os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER)


image_urls = ["20190411_123200.jpg", ... other images in a list]

class Photo_Index():
    def __init__(self, index=0):
        self.index = index

    def increase_number(self, num_images):
        if self.index == num_images:
            self.index = 0
        else:
            self.index = self.index + 1
        return self.index

    def decrease_number(self, num_images):
        if self.index == 0:
            self.index = num_images
        else:
            self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.index

    def random_number(self, num_images):
        self.index = random.randint(0, num_images)
        return self.index

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.index = number
        return self.index


# functions to create and edit Favorites. this works so I'm excluding]


def day_month_year(filename):
    """
    Takes a string `20190212` and pulls out Year, Month, Date
    """
    year = filename[:4]
    month = filename[4:6]
    day = filename[6:8]
    return str(year + "-" + month + "-" + day)


def get_files_on(specific_date):
    _files = []
    print("\nLooking for files on:", specific_date, "\n")
    for file in image_urls:
        # print(file, day_month_year(file))
        if day_month_year(file) == specific_date:
            _files.append(file)
    return _files


photo_index_obj = Photo_Index()
fav_photo_index = Photo_Index()


def update_index(rqst, indx_obj, num_images):
    print("Updating index, have", num_images, "photos")
    if num_images == 1:
        indx_obj.set_number(0)
    elif 'prev-photo' in rqst.form:
        indx_obj.decrease_number(num_images)
    elif 'next-photo' in rqst.form:
        indx_obj.increase_number(num_images)
    elif 'random-photo' in rqst.form:
        indx_obj.random_number(num_images)
    return indx_obj

@app.route("/<chosen_image>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def default_template(date=None, image_list=None, chosen_image=None):
    if image_list is None:
        image_list = image_urls
    num_images = len(image_list) - 1
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'go-to-date' in request.form:
            date = request.form['go-to-date']
            image_list = get_files_on(date)
            num_images = len(image_list) - 1
            photo_index_obj.set_number(0)
            if len(image_list) == 0:
                image_list = ["no_images_for_date.jpg"]
        elif 'prev-next-buttons' in request.form:
            print("Updating index, have", num_images, "photos")
            update_index(request, photo_index_obj, num_images)
        elif 'favorite-photo' in request.form:
            add_to_favorites(image_list[photo_index_obj.index])
        elif 'un-favorite-photo' in request.form:
            remove_from_favorites(image_list[photo_index_obj.index])
    if chosen_image is None:
        chosen_image = image_list[photo_index_obj.index]
    elif chosen_image is not None:
        photo_index_obj.set_number(image_list.index(chosen_image))
    favorite = is_favorite(image_list[photo_index_obj.index])
    print("Images:", image_list)
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title="Local Image Viewer",
                           photo_index=photo_index_obj.index,
                           image=chosen_image,
                           image_list=image_list,
                           favorite=favorite)

@app.route("/<chosen_image>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def chosen_image(chosen_image):
    date = request.form['go-to-date']
    return default_template(date=date,
                            chosen_image=chosen_image)
```

index.html (I omitted the Select list, as that's kind of superfluous for this post)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/index.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
</head>
<body>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h3>Index: {{ photo_index }}</h3>
    <h3>Filename: {{ image }}</h3>
    <div id="calendar-selector">
    {% include "/HTML Snippets/calendar.html" %}
    </div>
    <div class='image-container' id='image'>
        {% include "/HTML Snippets/favorite_button.html" %}
        <img src="{{ url_for('images.static', filename=image) }} " id="the-photo">
    </div>
    <div class='button-container' id='buttons'>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="prev-next-buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Prev photo" name='prev-photo'>
            <input type="submit" value="Next photo" name='next-photo'>
            <input type="submit" value="Random photo" name='random-photo'>
            <br/>
            <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMeCounterClockwise('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo CounterClockwise</button>
            <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMeClockwise('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo Clockwise</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='table-container'>
        <table id='image-list' name='select-from-table'>
            {% for image_row in image_list | batch(3) %}
            <tr>
                {% for image in image_row %}
                <td><a href="{{ url_for('default_template', chosen_image=image) }}"> {{ image }} </a></td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

and the calendar bit, calendar.html

```
{% block topscripts %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/calendar.css') }}">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        });
    </script>    
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('default_template') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="calendar-form">
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name='go-to-date'
        {% if request.form['go-to-date'] is not none %}
            value="{{request.form['go-to-date']}}"
        {% endif %}

        ></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block endscripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: There's a lot going on there to get my head around, but `photo_index=photo_index_obj.index` looks like it might be a decent hook. Can't you just track the image index that you previously served and pass it to/from the template?

Comment: @roganjosh - Yeah, sorry about all the code. I wanted to be more explicit, as in the past I've accidentally left out crucial bits...But yes, the `photo_index` is a great idea to use. ...so, would I just pass the index in to the HTML template, then retrieve again in the Flask routes.py somehow?

Comment: My approach, and really this is totally stumbled upon by myself and not taught (and by that I mean maybe not best practice), would be to store an object in a session that keeps track of what it last served. The other option would be to pass to the template as a hidden variable that gets retrieved. Anything that can maintain the state; I suspect pagination approaches would be applicable here, slightly re-purposed.

Comment: @roganjosh - If you notice, I send `image_list` to the `index.html` template, so the HTML page *does* have the list of photos. So the first time I have the calendar filter, it correctly passes in just those images.  I think what your first comment is saying, is that I could somehow, on page reload, "pull" that list back in to the routes.py, yes?  I'm racking my brain trying to think how to do that.  I *thought* I could by adding the `image_list` parameter to the `url_for` in each `a href` as I metioned at the start, but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas on how to do that more specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass along enough information in your next/previous form and in the table links to re-apply the date filter. Your calendar form is separate from the next/previous navigation form, the browser won't serialise information from one when submitting the other. Clicks on `<a href="...">` links will not include the date input field value either.

Note that clicks on the table links generate GET requests, so you need to look for `go-to-date` in the [`request.values` mapping](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.values) to accommodate both query parameters and form data.

You need to look for this parameter not only when you receive a `POST` request, but for all requests:

```
if 'go-to-date' in request.values:
    date = request.values['go-to-date']
    image_list = get_files_on(date)
    photo_index_obj.set_number(0)
    if len(image_list) == 0:
        image_list = ["no_images_for_date.jpg"]
else:
    image_list = image_list or image_urls
num_images = len(image_list) - 1

if request.method == 'POST':
    # ...
```

Then generate URLs that include the parameter:

```html
{%- set url_params = {'go-to-date': request.values['go-to-date']} if request.values['go-to-date'] else {} -%}
{% for image in image_row %}
<td><a href="{{ url_for('default_template', chosen_image=image, **url_params) }}"> {{ image }} </a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

For the `next/previous` form, just add a hidden input field with the current `go-to-date` value:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="prev-next-buttons">
    {%- if request.values['go-to-date'] -%}
    <input type="hidden" name="go-to-date" value="{{ request.values['go-to-date'] }}">
    {%- endif -%}

    <input type="submit" value="Prev photo" name='prev-photo'>
    <input type="submit" value="Next photo" name='next-photo'>
    <input type="submit" value="Random photo" name='random-photo'>
    <br/>
    <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMeCounterClockwise('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo CounterClockwise</button>
    <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMeClockwise('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo Clockwise</button>
</form>
```

Comment: OH MAN!! this is so close! When I first load the page, I can use next/prev buttons to go through all photos.  However, after I click a URL in the table, that specific image loads (good), but I can no longer loop through with next/prev. The page just stays on the same image. [See this .gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYqG3.gif).  When I choose a date, I can first scroll through ...kind of, it becomes a little wonky there. [See this .gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tharq.gif).  I'm reviewing what you said and am trying to understand it, but off the cuff do you know what I might be overlooking?

Comment: @BruceWayne: Look closely at the URL in your browser. The link takes you from `/` to `/date_image.jpg`. You need to handle this case with the next / previous buttons; the form posts to the *current* URL, so that won't change in the browser. You'd have to redirect the visitor at that point.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So, I'm now trying to do `<a href="{{ url_for('choose_image', ...` to then pass the info to that function, which then returns me up to `default_template`. Is that the way to do this or am I kludging my way through this, and overlooking something more obvious? (I apologize for the repeated questions, I'm learning Flask (...obviously) and have been working on this for a few days so my judgement/understanding is getting a little cloudy :(   )

Comment: @BruceWayne: basically, a web server sees each request as a totally new, independent query for a response. Each browser holds the current 'state', the location and other information that makes up the page. If you want to give the visitor the next response, you need to make sure that the request includes enough information to detect what the right next response should be. How you get that data from browser to server is up to you. You now have 2 forms and a set of links the user can interact with, and those now transfer enough information back to the server to make decisions about how to respond

Comment: @BruceWayne: I didn't pay attention to this before, but you are actually keeping too much state on your server, in the `photo_index_obj` global. If two different users come to your site, and one clicks 'next', the other user will wonder why the next time they load your site they see a different photo. Before you know it, multiple users hitting 'next' and 'previous' like mad will become completely bewildered. You want to keep that information *stored by the browser*. URLs are a great way of doing that.

Comment: @BruceWayne: You could use the `/` url purely to redirect a first-time visitor to the first photo URL, with the [`redirect()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.redirect), so the browser goes to `/date_number.jpg` for the first image. The `next` and `previous` buttons should then cause the browser to redirect to the appropriate `/date_number.jpg` URL for the next or previous images, taking into account the date filter.

Comment: (Note on the idea of this all: this is for a personal home server. I dump photos from my phone to a drive, and as a personal HTML/Flask learning project, I'm just trying to have a nice simple webpage to browse them with).  Thanks so much for your help, I'll digest it all and keep plugging away at it :D